# Pasar valor de target dinamicos a la función jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy intentando pasar el valor de un target dinámico a ua funcion jQuery pero no lo consigo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#target001").click(function(){ // sustituir '001' por el valor dinámico de CodRut
     var codRut = $("#target001").data('rut');  // sustituir '001' por el valor dinámico de CodRut
     var codDoc = $("#target001").data('doc');  // sustituir '001' por el valor dinámico de CodRut
     var nombrehueco = '#b_huecos'+codRut;    
     var mostrarhueco = '#mostrar_huecos'+codRut;      
     var dataString = 'codrut='+codRut+'&coddoc='+codDoc;
  jQuery.ajax({
  url: "consulta_externa.php",
  data: dataString,
  type: "POST",
  success:function(data){
   $(nombrehueco).show();    
   $(mostrarhueco).html(data); 
  },
  error:function (){}
  });
     });
});
```

Para que me funcione, tengo que repetir tantas funciones `$("#targetXXX").click(function()` como devuelva la consulta. He conseguido pasar el valor dinamico a la funcion ajax, pero no se como hacerlo en la funcion principal.
El valor viene del siguiente codigo PHP (un boton)

```html
<?php 
echo "<a href='#' id='buscahuecos".$nom['cod']."' name='buscahuecos".$nom['cod']."' data-rut='".$nom['cod']."' data-doc='".$coddoc."' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' role='button'>Localizar Huecos<br/><i class='icofont-search-document icofont-lg'></i></a>";
?>
```

Los valores dinamicos provienen de una consulta mysql, y dependiendo del valor de `$nom['cod']` puede ser `#target001`, `#target002`, `#target003`, ... hasta `#target030`.

Comment: podes cambiar los targets de id a clases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=target]').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
    console.log($(this).data('rut'));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target001" data-rut="001">001</div>
<div id="target002" data-rut="002">002</div>
<div id="target003" data-rut="003">003</div>
```

También puedes simplemente usar una clase para los elementos, y usar `$(this)` cuando quieras a acceder al que se haya clickado.

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Muchisimas gracias :-)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una clase para el elemento y obtener el valor con `attr()` de jQuery.

```js
$(".obtenerAtributo").click(function(){

//Así obtienes el valor del atributo
var atributo1 = $(this).attr("atributo1");
console.log("valor:"+atributo1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" atributo1="0001" class="obtenerAtributo">0001</a><br/>
<a href="#" atributo1="1000" class="obtenerAtributo">1000</a><br/>
<a href="#" atributo1="Texto" class="obtenerAtributo">Texto</a><br/>
<a href="#" atributo1="XXXXXX" class="obtenerAtributo">XXXXXX</a><br/>
<a href="#" atributo1="20154" class="obtenerAtributo">20154</a><br/>
```

Comment: A la hora de agregar datos personalizados a una etiqueta HTML es recomendable hacer uso de [los atributos `data-*` (dataset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: Es cierto, lo tendré en cuenta para futuras respuestas y proyectos.